# PKIX path building failed:certificate missing

Tags: java, database, oracle

I created a free Oracle DB and I'am trying to connect to it via IntelliJ Database Tools.

I keep getting this error.

[08006][17002] I/O-Fehler: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, connect lapse 32 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms. sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Where can I get this certificate?

Please help (newbie here already spent like 2 days on this)

Comment: Have you read and tried [this Oracle suggestion](https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target)?

Comment: This helped Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the link to the suggestion is not working I would recommend the following solution, which works in my case:

1. Get the database certificate

You may use the following bash command for this:

```sh
openssl s_client -connect example.com:1234 -servername example.com:1234 < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cert.crt
```

Just replace the `example.com:1234` with your host and port. The database certificate will be saved as `cert.crt`.

2. Add the certificate to the IntelliJ database connection properties window like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem though I was using all maven dependencies required.
I tried connecting SQL Server database using Java.

This issues resolved just like that by adding the right version (Compatible for your Database server version).

I changed the `mssql-jdbc` version from `8.2.1.jre11` to `8.4.1.jre11`. Hope this would help somebody

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.1.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```